# Insert python list into SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a query which should insert the contents of a list to a table.  It's my understanding that each %s should be replaced by the content of the valueInsert list I've added to the execute command.

However I get the following error

> c.executemany(test4, valuesInsert)
>
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Query:

```
test4 = "INSERT INTO test (city,region_code,os,ip,isp,area_code,\
    dma_code,last_update,country_code3,country_name,postal_code,\
        longitude,country_code,ip_str,latitude,org,asn) VALUES \
            (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

Command to execute query

```
c.executemany(test4, valuesInsert)
```

Contents of List:

```
['Norwell', 'MA', None, 1572395042, 'EdgeCast Networks', 781, 506, '2019-12-09T00:44:43.812333', 'USA', 'United States', '02061', -70.8217, 'US', '93.184.216.34', 42.15960000000001, 'Verizon Business', 'AS15133']
```

Comment: can you print first test4 before ???

Comment: @alecxe When using `"INSERT INTO test (city,region_code,os,ip,isp,area_code,\
    dma_code,last_update,country_code3,country_name,postal_code,\
        longitude,country_code,ip_str,latitude,org,asn) VALUES \
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"` I get the error `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 17, and there are 7 supplied.`
but when I print the list I'm seeing 17 attributes

Comment: in `executemany` you should use list of lists - `[ ['Norwell',... ], ['other place', ...], ]` for single element (like yours) you have `execute()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executemany` doesn't mean many arguments in one `INSERT`.

`executemany` is used when you have list of lists - data for many rows in database - and you want to execute many `INSERT`

```
valuesInsert = [ 
    ['Norwell',... ], 
    ['Other Place', ...], 
]


c.executemany(test4, valuesInsert)
```

but you have only one element - data for one row in database - and you want to execute only one `INSERT` so you should use `execute()`

```
valuesInsert = ['Norwell',... ]

c.execute(test4, valuesInsert)
```

---

**BTW:**  when you use `['Norwell',... ]` with `executemany` then it get `'Norwell'` as data for first row (for first `INSERT`) and threat string as list of chars.

```
valuesInsert = [ 
    ['N', 'o', 'r', 'w', 'e', 'l', 'l'] 
]
```

Because `'Norwell'` has 7 chars so it see 7 elements and you get message `The current statement uses 17, and there are 7 supplied`.

Comment: Thanks for this, helped a ton. 
I've changed to just execute. 
My new problem is that it's still not writing to the database but I get no error code :(

Comment: Nevermind! running the execute command with conn inserted the data
`with conn:
    c.execute(test4, valuesInsert)`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code can help you (this example just use columns type text)

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("samples.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cmd = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2 (city text,region_code text,os text,ip text,isp text,area_code text, dma_code text,last_update text,country_code3 text,country_name text,postal_code text, longitude text,country_code text,ip_str text ,latitude text,org text ,asn text)"
cur.execute(cmd)

list1 = ['Norwell', 'MA', None, 1572395042, 'EdgeCast Networks', 781, 506, '2019-12-09T00:44:43.812333', 'USA', 'United States', '02061', -70.8217, 'US', '93.184.216.34', 42.15960000000001, 'Verizon Business', 'AS15133']
list2 = ['Norwell', 'MA', None, 1572395042, 'EdgeCast Networks', 781, 506, '2019-12-09T00:44:43.812333', 'USA', 'United States', '02061', -70.8217, 'US', '93.184.216.34', 42.15960000000001, 'Verizon Business', 'AS15133']

con.executemany("INSERT INTO test2(city,region_code,os,ip,isp,area_code, dma_code,last_update,country_code3,country_name,postal_code, longitude,country_code,ip_str,latitude,org,asn) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (list1, list2))

for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test2"):

    print (row)
```